# Flask ' application not registered on db'

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, flask

I tried to check answers to other questions with the same error. But the situation of those seem different from mine.
I can use Role.query.all() in .\xxxapp\admin\views.py, but when I call Role.query.all() in .\xxxapp\admin\forms.py, I got this:

```
raise RuntimeError('application not registered on db '
RuntimeError: application not registered on db instance and no application bound to current context
```

My folders are like this:

```
      .\
      |-xxxapp\
      |  |-admin\
      |  |  |__init__.py
      |  |  |forms.py
      |  |  |views.py
      |  |-user\
      |  |  |__init__.py
      |  |  |forms.py
      |  |  |models.py
      |  |  |views.py
      |  |....
      |  |-extensions.py
      |  |-app.py
      |manage.py
```

app is created in .\xxxapp\extensions.py by a app creator function 'create_app', and db is created in .\xxxapp\extensions.py. All initiators such as db.init(app) are called in 'create_app'. While 'create_app' is called in manage.py. I don't understand why in views.py app and db know each other while in forms.py they don't.

Now here is my code in .\xxxapp\admin\views.py

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from xxxapp.user.models import User, Role

class UserForm(Form):
      roles = Role.query.all()  # this doesn't work
      ...
```

and .\xxxapp\admin\models.py

```
from flask import (current_app, Blueprint, request, render_template, flash, url_for, redirect, session)
from flask.ext.user import current_user, login_required, roles_required
from xxxapp.extensions import db, user_manager
from xxxapp.user.models import User, Role

blueprint = Blueprint('admin', __name__, static_folder="../static")

@blueprint.route('/user/<int:user_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
@roles_required('admin')    
def user(user_id):
    roles = Role.query.all()  #this works
```

Class Role is defined in .\xxxapp\user\models.py:

```
from xxxapp.extensions import db

.....

class Role(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(255))
```

app factory in app.py contains:

```
...(imported modules are omitted)
...
__all__ = ['create_app']

DEFAULT_BLUEPRINTS = (frontend,d5user,api,admin)
def create_app(config=None, app_name=None, blueprints=None):
    if app_name is None:
        app_name = DefaultConfig.PROJECT
    if blueprints is None:
        blueprints = DEFAULT_BLUEPRINTS
    app = Flask(import_name=app_name, instance_path=INSTANCE_FOLDER_PATH, instance_relative_config=True)

    app.config.from_object(DefaultConfig)          
    mail = Mail(app)

    init_error_logger_with_email_handler(app)
    register_extensions(app)
    register_blueprints(app, blueprints)
    register_errorhandlers(app)
    configure_template_filters(app)

    return app

def register_blueprints(app, blueprints):
    for blt in blueprints:
        app.register_blueprint(blt)

def register_extensions(app):
    assets.init_app(app)
    bcrypt.init_app(app)
    cache.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)
    debug_toolbar.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
    user_manager.init_app(app)     # Init Flask-User and bind to app
    return None

... more registration function are omitted.
```

I must have missed something, but have no clue where. Maybe it is an easy problem for experienced. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Just guessing. Did you register your blueprint? Basic idea is here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/blueprints/#registering-blueprints

Comment: @Gohn67 yes, I did register the blueprints. I've just edited the question at the bottom to reflect this.